# Replaying network requests from HAR like PlayWright in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, playwright, har

Is there a way to replay API requests to a specific URL (possibly via a .har file). PlayWright has a feature like this called routeFromHAR (https://playwright.dev/docs/mock#mocking-with-har-files) that does exactly this but that's specific to PlayWrite and I'd like a way to do it in plain Chrome.

So, for example, any requests to https://api.com/v1/* gets routed to a HAR file with saved responses, but anything else doesn't. The aim is to remove delays so when I refresh a frontend project I don't have to wait for the real API to respond which takes time, this way it should be instant.

Comment: Please show us code. Normally, questions without any code get ignored